# Windows Phone 7 Listbox selection data binding

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox, listboxitem

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/build-your-first-windows-phone-7-app) as a base for my first app. I'm trying to select a listbox item and view data from said item, but(my Android and iOS brain is having issues with this), how do I view the data binding behind that?

```
lstContact.ItemsSource = from contact in xmlContact.Descendants("contact")
                                 select new ContactItem
                                 {
                                     ImageSource = contact.Element("Image").Value,
                                     FName = contact.Element("FName").Value,
                                     LName = contact.Element("LName").Value
                                     Extension = contact.Element("Extension").Value,
                                     Email = contact.Element("Email").Value,
                                     ID = contact.Element("ID").Value
                                 };
```

This is how I'm setting it up my data source, and it's pulling correctly. How would I go about going in and getting the email or extension from said listbox item?

Comment: lstContact.ItemsSource is effectively now a IEnumerable<ContactItem>. Assuming you want a 'selected' item, are you listening to SelectionChanged?

Comment: if (lstContact.SelectedIndex == -1) return; var contactItem = (ContactItem)lstContact.SelectedItem; /*do something */ lstContact.SelectedIndex = -1;

Comment: That worked perfectly! Mind sticking that in an answer so I can accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `lstContact.ItemsSource` is effectively now a `IEnumerable<ContactItem>`. Assuming you want a 'selected' item, in your `SelectionChanged` event:

```
public void ListBoxContainerSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lstContact.SelectedIndex == -1) return; 
            ContactItem contactItem = (ContactItem)lstContact.SelectedItem; 
            /*do something */ 
            lstContact.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```